# Prove that $f$ is $\mathcal S$-measurable iff $f^+$ and $f^{-}$ are both $\mathcal S$-measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, measurable-functions

Let $(X,\mathcal S)$ be a measurable space. Let $f : X \longrightarrow \Bbb R^*$ be a map. Then the following are equivalent.

$(1)$ $f^{-1} (c, \infty] \in \mathcal S$ for every $c \in \Bbb R.$

$(2)$ $f^{-1} [c, \infty] \in \mathcal S$ for every $c \in \Bbb R.$

$(3)$ $f^{-1} [-\infty, c) \in \mathcal S$ for every $c \in \Bbb R.$

$(4)$ $f^{-1} [-\infty, c] \in \mathcal S$ for every $c \in \Bbb R.$

$(5)$ $f^{-1} \{\infty\}, f^{-1} \{-\infty\} \in \mathcal S$ and $f^{-1} (E) \in \mathcal S$ for every $E \in \mathcal B_{\Bbb R}.$

If $f$ will satisfy any of the properties $(1) - (5)$ mentioned above $f$ is said to be an $\mathcal S$-measurable function.

Now for any $f : X \longrightarrow \Bbb R^*$ define two functions $f^+$ and $f^{-}$ in the following way $:$

$$
f^+(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            f(x) & \quad \text {if}\ f(x) \geq 0 \\
            0 & \quad \text {if}\ f(x) \lt 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

$$
f^-(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            -f(x) & \quad \text {if}\ f(x) \leq 0 \\
            0 & \quad \text {if}\ f(x) \gt 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Now I am studying these things from NPTEL lecture series on *Measure and Integration* by Inder K. Rana. What he claimed in one of his lectures is the following $:$

A function $f : X \longrightarrow \Bbb R^*$ is $\mathcal S$-measurable iff both $f^+$ and $f^-$ are $\mathcal S$-measurable. He claimed that 
$$
({f^+})^{-1}[c,\infty] = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            f^{-1}[c,\infty] & \quad \text {if}\ c \geq 0 \\
            f^{-1} [0,\infty] & \quad \text {if}\ c \lt 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Similar things happen for $f^{-}.$ I think he (the instructor) made a mistake here. I think instead the following will be correct.

$$({f^+})^{-1}[c,\infty] = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            f^{-1}[c,\infty] & \quad \text {if}\ c \gt 0 \\
            X & \quad \text {if}\ c \leq 0
        \end{array}
    \right.$$

Can anybody please verify it? Thanks in advance.

**Source** $:$ 
https://youtu.be/R9E7vqJDn3I?list=PLtKWB-wrvn4mbGE2XeUbnVw1cwAj4-f0C&t=290

Comment: Yes, you are correct and the book is wrong.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy sir similarly $$({f^-})^{-1}[c,\infty] = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            f^{-1}[-\infty,-c] & \quad \text {if}\ c \gt 0 \\
            X & \quad \text {if}\ c \leq 0
        \end{array}
    \right.$$ Am I right sir?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.